# Is there a way to format decimal in razor view cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am creating a product view page and I am trying to format a price, which is a decimal, into a string output like this: 1.55 => £1,55. I'm trying to use product.Price.ToString("N2") but this is not doing the trick, I need the dot to be a comma[image]. Is there any other way to do this in the actual .cshtml file?

[image]

Comment: `1.55m.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))` for me produces a dot, meaning the standard separator for UK is a dot though.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I could even leave it as just £@product.Price and it would be right. Thanks for your reply mate, upVote for you!